# Efficient / elegant two dimensional container

Tags: c++

Need for two dimensional array of objects that could be something like:

```
myContainer<myObject*> *a = new myArray<myObject*>( 20, 20 ); // passing int's as width & height
```

later accessing values would be done with methods such as:

```
mylist<myObject*> getRow( int );
mylist<myObject*> getColumn( int );
mylist<myObject*> getDiagonalRow( int );
```

implementations of those could be something like:

```
myList<myObject*> myContainer::getRow( int a ){
    if( a < 0 && a>=this->height ) 
        return; 
    myList<myObject*> hlp;
    for( int i=0; i<this->width; i++)
        hlp.append( this->arr[a][i] );
    return hlp; // returns a copy. Could also be a pointer if created with new.
}
```

Other methods could follow similar lines, ie. creating a list object and filling it with what was requested.

My questions: Can anyone think of elegant way to create a container class I'm describing here. Which could for example avoid creating and filling of list-objects but still maintaining the abstraction and/or usability. Or please advice if I have missed something in STL etc. that has something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STL has the valarray container which can be viewed as row and columns using slices, but you have to do it manually or wrap it into a wrapper class. Also the slices represents the values of the valarray (they are not a copy), but it is designed to be used with numbers and to be a bit optimized, it doesn't have any iterator and cannot be grown. it's doesn't follow the usual STL container concept. but it can still be used as a quick and dirty workaround if you can't use boost.

```
std::valarray<float> array(16);
// we can view it as a 4x4 matrix.
// this represents the first line
array[std::slice(0,4,1)];
// and the second column
array[std::slice(1,4,4)];
// you cannot use the sliced array directly. they don't
// have operator[], but they have operator=(valarray), and
// valarray has a constructor that takes sliced arrays as input.
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the speed you are aiming for? 
I can image to get a getRow() and getColumn() and getDiagonal()
in constant time when you handle with something list-like in the background.e.g. vector.
(if you just return a pointer)

Should the container grow or is the size fixed after the initialization?

If your container size is m and n you can store m std::vectors of size n,
n std::vectors of size m, and m+n std::vectors of different sizes.
Describing the rows, coloumns, and diagonals.
Then the get methods are easy to implement and in a at() or [] method/operator
three entries are to be changed.

Comment: I was missing just something like BatchyX showed here. Maybe I have to write slice for diagonals myself but now knowing about existence of std::slice helps a lot.